# Set custom java.rmi.server.hostname for each Spark executor

Tags: java, apache-spark, jmx, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark process running on YARN (with like 10 workers and 10 hosts), and I'd like to be able to use JMX on the executors.
Let's say to simplify that I'm sure there will be at most one executor on each host (to avoid port conflicts).

Using `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` on the Spark Conf is not possible, because each host needs to have a different `java.rmi.server.hostname`.

I don't find a way to set custom java options per YARN container/Spark executor, how would you proceed ?

I think it should be set dynamically with `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", ...)` but I don't have any hook "when executor starts". Do I ?

Comment: But all these executors don't really have a different hostname, do they?

Comment: Yes they have. Spark is running in yarn mode. So, executors are dispatched on all hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar to this in `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9999 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
```